# Как проверить, есть ли в БД Firebase пользователь с определенным mail'ом?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase

При регистрации в приложении пользователь должен заполнить несколько textField'ов, среди которых присутствует email. Как мне следует проверять БД на наличие такого же мейла, для вывода ошибки?

БД в формате JSON выглядит вот так: 
[image: JSON]

Answer (score 0):

```
new Firebase("https://examples-sql-queries.firebaseio.com/user") 
.startAt('example@gmail.com') 
.endAt('example@gmail.com') 
.once('value', function(snap) {
 console.log('accounts matching email address', snap.val()) 
});
```